# How to compare two strings and remove the elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two strings.

```
str1 = "Door no:1/3/4-A, phase 2, banjara, delhi, 123456"
str2 = "delhi"
```

My question is, First I need to compare this two strings and I need to remove the elements after that compared string. For example, if `delhi` is located in the `str1` then I need to remove the entire data after the `delhi` in the `str1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str1 = "Door no:1/3/4-A, phase 2, banjara, delhi, 123456",
    str2 = "delhi";

str1 = str1.split(str2)[0] + str2;

alert(str1);
```

Here, the `split` function splits your string into an array separating it on the word `str2`. Then you take the first part, and append `str2` back to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (str1.indexOf(str2) !== -1) { 
  str1.substr(0, str1.indexOf(str2) + str2.length);
}
```